# No listener when call state reject on voice phone

Tags: android, sinch

iam using app to phone sinch call, when user execute call, everything fine from call progressing until call ended, but when another user reject the phone call, listener from first user not return anything, is there any clue/information about this, really appreciate anything to make it clear.

Comment: Have you check for "TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK" state?

Comment: i havent check that, but i think, Sinch already have listener to handle 'reject' call state,

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create a BroadcastReceiver which receive your call state and using that you can implement your another logic.

Here is demo for call receiver :

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE))){
        Log.d("mytag","call ringing");

        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

//            Toast.makeText(context, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE))){
```

String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

Toast.makeText(context, "Call Ended.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
    }

}
```

}

Add these in your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".phonemidea.IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: thanks for the example, but i think, sinch already have listener for this, next time i will try youre suggestion anyway